# How do I lock table cells of a Google Docs document?

Tags: google-docs

I need to lock certain cells in a table within Google Docs. The other cells I want people to be able to edit. How can I selectively lock cells in a document?

Answer (score 1):

At this time it's not possible to lock parts of a document (text processor file) in Google Documents.

Comment: @Steve: On this site we upvote/accept answers if they are helpful. (Reference [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) ). :)